# How to merge GoogleAnalytics and Firebase/Crashlytics GoogleService-info.plist?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-fabric, firebase-crash-reporting

**How to merge GoogleAnalytics and Firebase/Crashlytics GoogleService-info.plist?**

In an iOS project, I have been using GoogleAnalytics and Fabric. Now I am trying to migrate Fabric to Firebase/Crashlytics. GoogleAnalytics has been using a GoogleService-info.plist and also Firebase requires a GoogleService-info.plist to [support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk). Although I am using same account. Both GOOGLE_APP_ID is showing different in both GoogleService-info.plist. How can I use both version of GoogleAnalitics and Firebase/Crashlytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked,

We can remove the old **GoogleAnalytics GoogleService-info.plist** and dynamically set GA configurations like below ([more detail](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2583-google-analytics-for-ios)),

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXXXXX-Y"];
```

Then for [Firebase/Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios) GoogleService-info.plist, we can put in appropriate dev/prod folder and copy appropriate one in Build Phase -> Run Script based on configurations. Like,

```
# Name of the resource we're selectively copying
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist

# Get references to dev and prod versions of the GoogleService-Info.plist
# NOTE: These should only live on the file system and should NOT be part of the target (since we'll be adding them to the target manually)
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Firebase/Dev/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Firebase/Prod/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

# Make sure the dev version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV ]
then
    echo "No Development GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
    exit 1
fi

# Make sure the prod version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD ]
then
    echo "No Production GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
    exit 1
fi

# Get a reference to the destination location for the GoogleService-Info.plist
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
echo "Will copy ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} to final destination: ${PLIST_DESTINATION}"

# Copy over the prod GoogleService-Info.plist for Release builds
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]
then
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
else
    echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
    cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
fi
```